# How to check if optional object property exists?

Tags: javascript, typescript, record

I'm having trouble getting TypeScript to recognise that an optional property of an object is defined.

```
type OuterKeys = 'a' | 'b';

type Inner = {
    value: '';
}

type Outer = Partial<Record<OuterKeys, Inner>>;

const thisGivesError = (key: OuterKeys, outer: Outer) => {
    if (outer[key]) {
        console.log(outer[key].value);
    }
}
```

Even though I explicitly check if `outer[key]` is defined, I'm getting error when trying to access `outer[key].value`: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

How can I work around it? The only way I found is assigning `outer[key]` to a variable and having another `if`, like below. Is this the only way to go?

```
const thisWorks = (key: OuterKeys, outer: Outer) => {
    const o = outer[key];
    if (o) {
      console.log(o.value);
    }    
}
```

The playground with the code can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsCAnA0hEBnKBeKByAQzygB98AjPAbgCgbRIoBJAOxeRygG8ao+oAbgQA2cCAC581GgF86DaPERJOABQJJgASxEAeAEoQAxgHskAE11LkaTABpmbZAD5ntGqZYZgUYAAstDABxLQEIDABRJCQzTgAKAGt0SWtUdAwHEwRkFOykAEocZ25efi0AMyg4rOUAbSSQAF1Cnn42qE8ME2EIADphEwBzarz69EbeoVEIfNo2uTkPEy8ff0CAdTMErFxE5Ng82wyoGpyD5ULsYtb2vk6fE05TpDGmuduoCqqTFtKPjuWXR6-SG1UmIjEsz+7RkbVkQA)

**Edit:** I don't want to use `!` operator, as it feels like a workaround - why would I tell TypeScript that this value is set using non-null assertion, if I already checked for its existence with `if`? Same for `.?` - I already have the `if`, so this value for sure exists and is not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530), currently TS doesn't narrow down on indexed access.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner object which holds the value is never specified to not be undefined.
You can fix this by simply adding a question mark.

Ex adding a question mark:

```
const thisGivesError = (key: OuterKeys, outer: Outer) => {
    if (outer[key]) {
        console.log(outer[key]?.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, after checking for `outer[key]` being truthy, it's safe to go with non-null assertion:

```
if (outer[key]) {
    console.log(outer[key]!.value);
}
```

Though I don't know how to make TypeScript figure it out on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `object?.key` operator. You can learn more about it [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/4-cool-modern-javascript-features-most-developers-dont-know-about-c2c45104427c).

Your final code will be:

```
const thisWorks = (key: OuterKeys, outer: Outer) => {
  if (outer[key]) {
    console.log(outer[key]?.value);
  }    
}
```